# How to use jquery validation plugin in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

How to use **jquery validation plugin** for the **rails form** given below.

I want complete steps about how to make the it for different fields.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :firstname %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :lastname %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :mobile %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :mobile %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

plz help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First include the jquery validation file in your layout. Then in rails form add class to validation required fields as <%= f.text_field :firstname, :class => "required" %>. Then write  a method with form_id to trigger the validation. That is you have to give like

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $("your_form_id").validate();  
});
```

Comment: Thats great ..but how to do it for email,mobile,password,password confirmation.As they require the name field to be same as in javascript

Comment: You can give email validation as in class field itself. like <%= f.text_field :firstname, :class => "required email" %>

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [jquery validation rails](https://github.com/danryan/jquery-validation-rails) gem based on [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). To use it

1. Add the gem to your gemfile `gem 'jquery-validation-rails'`
2. On your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` add the following lines

   `//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods 
   //= require jquery.validate`
3. As of turbolinks 5 which is included in rails 5 instead of using `$(document).ready` use `$(document).on "turbolinks:load"` as described in turbolinks [readme](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)

Comment: not a good idea to use gem for js plugin.. we can simply add any plugin without any gem

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution to add **range ,min ,max** etc

we have to use

```
   <%= f.text_field :mobile,:class => "required number",:minlength=>"10",
   :maxlength=>"10"%>
```

the above for mobile